# ToolingAPI bug? Dev Console only: No such column 'PoNumber' on entity 'Order'

Tags: soql, query, developer-console, tooling-api, order

According to [the Docs for the standard `Order` Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_order.htm), `PoNumber` is a valid field on the object.  I have a query that references that field in an Apex class, and the class compiles, and the unit tests pass.  All set.

But.  Trying to run a few lines of code including that query in the Dev Console's Anonymous Apex window gives the error

> No such column 'PoNumber' on entity 'Order'

I then tried running the query in the Console's query tab; same issue.  Then I tried inspecting the object definition in the Console (Ctrl-Shift-O, Order.obj); that field isn't listed.  But it's list in Setup, and I can reference it from code.  Interestingly, I can edit/save the Apex Class containing the query from Dev Console.  Here's a simplified version of my query which exhibits this behavior:

```
select id, OrderNumber, EffectiveDate, PoNumber from Order
```

Is this a known issue?  Am I overlooking something special about Order.PoNumber?

Comment: Did you check FLS?

Comment: facepalm.  As a wise one man once said, "It's almost always a permissions issue."  Didn't think of it because the object should have default perms; I assumed sysadmin would have FLS for all standard fields by default.  Either that's not the case or someone has changed the defaults unexpectedly.  Please post as answer so I can accept, and thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is most commonly observed when trying to query on a field you do not have read access to via `Field Level Security`. Navigate to that field in the `Setup` menu, then click the <kbd>Set Field-Level Security</kbd> button. Make sure you have read access.